# Xcode Debugger Output Isn't Specific When Error Is Encountered

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm sure Xcode used to explain what the problem was when something went wrong at runtime, now I'm just getting the generic console message:

`terminating with uncaught exception of type nsexception`

The code execution has broken on AppDelegate with `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`

[image: SIGABRT]

I've been developing a UITableView with a few different prototype cells.

I don't know how to get Xcode to be more specific about the problem, do you?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Activate exception breakpoints]

Also, try to check ReuseIdentifiers, Outlet's, and if you registered your Xib's if you are using Custom Cells

Comment: Thanks! It was a broken IBOutlet connection.